# Select element with specific data by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Is it possible to set some data by using the jQuery data method and then later query it? Something like ... find all elements with data foo == true?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to select the elements you want, like this:

```
$("someSelector").filter(function() { return $.data(this, "foo"); });
```

In this case since you're checking a boolean it's very simple, for checking against a value just add the comparison, like this:

```
$("someSelector").filter(function() { return $.data(this, "foo") == "value"; });
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `$.data(this, 'foo')` over `$(this).data('foo')`?

Comment: @Matt - No wasted jQuery object :)

Comment: This did not work form me. I do not understand why you evaluate `$.data(this, "foo") == "value";` for me it worked by replacing it with `$.data(this).foo.id == "idValue";`. Thanks for the tip though! Really helped me out!

Comment: @Xeroxoid - In your case you're checking for the `id` property *on* `foo`, not just `foo`. To compare, in my example you'd need `$.data(this, "foo").id` not just `$.data(this, "foo")` to have an equivalent comparison.

Comment: My document is using HTML5 data-foo attribute and if I use your example on load it doesn't work, but `$(this).data('foo')` works fine. Strangely enough, on "select" elements it starts working when value changes on select.

Comment: @steelaz - the above method only works if the element has data stored...data attributes are handled differently, and must be accessed (at least the first time) by `.data('name')` which goes and looks at attributes, while `$.data(obj, 'name')` only looks directly at the data object store within jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible with just the `data` API without looping through each element in the DOM, and checking to see if it contains that data item with the specified value.

If the data is simple, perhaps you can use HTML5 data attributes which are also searchable through selectors.

```
$("selector").attr("data-key", "theKey");
```

Later select all objects that have an attribute named `"data-key"` with the value `true` using

```
$('[data-key="true"]')
```

Comment: thanks very much. i forgot that jquery not always save these data in element :)